# How to restore the Lumia 1020 with native applications and Windows 8.0?

Tags: apps, nokia-lumia-1020, reset

I updated my Lumia 1020 with Windows 8.1 and came across the error 80072f8f.

I searched solutions for this error and I opted for the hard reset.

However the native applications were uninstalled. I imagined it would be a restoration as occurs in notebooks.

But it simply deleted the native applications and has maintained Windows 8.1.

Is there a way to restore the device with native applications such as Nokia Pro Cam?

Is there a software to do that, a file image of the manufacturer to restore the phone?

Thanks.

Comment: there's lumia camera, why would you wanna use pro cam??

Comment: Second half of 2016 year is here and yet we have users how wants WP8.0 and after 8.1 and W10M. It's inetersting

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Store.
2. Go to My Library.
3. You can find all your apps there.
4. Install the apps you want.

Answer (score 0):

Download windows recovery tool on your PC. Plug your phone with USB cabel in your PC and start program. Follow instruction and you will go back to W8.0